# I want to display all personnel records that the current time is not between to the (column)start_time and end_time(column)

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display all personnel records that the current time is not between to the (column)start_time and end_time(column) but if the current time is between to the (column)start_time and end_time(column) then dont display the personnel name.

```
Sched_time_start = '17:00:00';     
Sched_time_end = '17:35:00';     
$time=date("h:i:s");//this is my current time variable//
```

here's my query code:

```
$qry= "SELECT * from personel as A Left join sched as B on A.Per_ID = B.Sched_Per_ID where '$time' NOT BETWEEN B.Sched_time_start AND B.Sched_time_end";     
$qryres = mysqli_query($connect, $qry);
```

so I dont want to display the personnel if the current time is between '17:00:00' and '17:35:00' but when the current time is bellow 16:59;00 or 17:36:00 above then the personnel name display on my select option

here's my select option code:

```
<select>     
<?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($qryres)) { ?>     
<option><?php echo $rows['Per_fname']; ?></option>     
<?php } ?>     
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It could be multiple things:

1. You're formatting the time with a lower `h`: `date("h:i:s");`. This will return the 12-hour format and not the 24-hour format, So this should be: `date("H:i:s");`. See: [PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more information.
2. If you're using the `DATETIME` instead of `TIME` type in your MYSQL table structure for the schedule start and end columns you'll have to include the day, month and year in your `$time` variable.